# Finding Jordan Normal Form And Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Let $0\neq A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$
>   
>   Such that $R(A)\perp C(A)$ 
>   
>   What are the Rank(A) and $A$ jordan normal form?

How should I approach this?

Comment: What is $C(A)$? $R(A)$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Column space and Row space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C(A)\bot R(A)$, then immediately $A^2=0\ne A$. Therefore, all eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are zero.

If the matrix $A$ has only one Jordan cell of order $3$, then, by easy calculation, $A^2\ne 0=A^3$, therefore, all Jordan cells in the Jordan normal form are of order at most $2$.

If all cells are of order $1$, then the whole matrix is zero, which is prohibited.

Thus, the Jordan normal form consists of one Jordan cell of order $2$ and one Jordan cell of order $1$; one can say that $A$ is equivalent to $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$hence $rank(A)=1$.

Comment: Can we conclude that the minimal polynomial is $\lambda^2$ as it the lowest order polynomial that divide the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3$ and $\lambda^2=0$ as you said.
So the biggest Jordan cell is of order 2 and the matrix of size 3 and therefore the Jordan normal form is as you written?

Comment: @gbox yes, you can. That's exactly the same reasoning, just formulated in other terms.